# Change background of a Div depending of HTML, without modfying CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got a page where a user can post a form with an uploaded image and a title.

A PHP script will generate a new page, replacing things on the sample like title with the user input.

I wanna put the uploaded image as background of my page.

I still want to use the same CSS for each page because generating a new one for each page is too heavy.

Since my HTML pages don't have a fixed name, I can't just treat the case in CSS.

I tried using some JS at the end of my html page but the image doesn't appear in this case. Seems like some properties doesn't apply to the new background but I'm not sure of this.

I also tried including a style element in the head of my HTML but same as with JS, the image doesn't appear.

My page is mostly based on this codepen : https://codepen.io/BarryKe/pen/advLWa
And here is a custom codepen of exactly my situation :https://codepen.io/Cryoclass/pen/LYrzGre

Does someone see a (simple ?) solution of how to do it ?
*Thanks in advance !*

```js
var el = document.getElementById('chg-bg');
el.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://via.placeholder.com/800/ff0000)";
```

```css
.hero-image {
  top: -20rem;
  bottom: -20rem;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://www.howlatthemoon.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/nyc-skyline.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hero h1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 20rem;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* Default header styles */

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #222222;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.75rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.6875rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.375rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}


/* Base element styles */

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #222222;
}

a,
a:hover {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  margin: 2rem 0;
  list-style: disc;
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

ul li {
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

p {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.content {
  max-width: 60rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.hero {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30rem;
}

section {
  padding: 6rem 0 3rem;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:darkgrey">
  <div class="hero" id="top">
    <div class="hero-image" id="chg-bg"></div>
    <h1>Do more, with less.</h1>
  </div>
  <section id="vision">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>We Have a Vision</h1>
      <h2>For a world where users come first</h2>
      <p>Latte ideate unicorn food-truck hacker latte disrupt integrate user story latte. Innovate viral food-truck paradigm user story food-truck quantitative vs. qualitative responsive intuitive parallax. Disrupt engaging bootstrapping iterate pivot fund
        venture capita</p>
      <p>Bootstrapping ship it pair programming waterfall is so 2000 and late food-truck long shadow venture capital ship it moleskine sticky not</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Where _user input_ is taken into account here? Have you inspected what kind of image browser tries to load and if it's URL is correct? Also your `.hero-image` has no content or defined height, so it will be not visible

Comment: *"depending on user input"* ? what input? If you're using PHP, what stops you to i.e: serve a page with some class addedd to the i.e: `<body class="<?= $somePHPVar ?>"`? JavaScript? What is the case in which you want to ... well... change the background?

Comment: I take user input is at the generation of the page. The user is posting some datas and a PHP script is creating from scratch a new page, resulting in sample_page.html. among those datas, there is a link to a picture stored that is moved on my server using move_uploaded_file.
I'm going to edit my post so it's more clear.

And, I frogot a part in the CSS saying .hero height is 30rem.

I will edit this now.

Comment: Take a look at the demo I've added to your post. In the future, that's what you should give us so we can see the problem clearly. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Comment: That was a path issue. Sorry for disturbing you and thanks for all the tips when it comes to posting questions.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just put the style code directly?

```
<div class="hero-image" style='background-image: url(https://placeholder.com/800) !important;'></div>
```

Comment: Avoid `!important` at all costs. Forget it actually exists.